# turborepo getting error with pnpm ( Cannot find module '/app/apps/backend/pnpm' )

Tags: node.js, docker, pnpm, turborepo

I'm getting this error while i was triying to run my  dockerfile

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
Error: Cannot find module '/app/apps/backend/pnpm'

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
exited with code 1

Here is the dockerfile :

```
FROM node:18 AS base

FROM base AS builder

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install  -g turbo
COPY . .
RUN turbo prune --scope=api --docker  
# here --scope=api is the name of the workspace. that is api is the name of the workspace in the package.json

# Add lockfile and package.json's of isolated subworkspace
FROM base AS installer
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
WORKDIR /app

# First install dependencies (as they change less often)
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /app/out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /app/out/pnpm.lock.yml ./pnpm-lock.yml
RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN pnpm install --from-lock-file --frozen-lockfile

# Build the project and its dependencies
COPY --from=builder /app/out/full/ .
RUN pnpm dlx prisma generate
COPY turbo.json turbo.json
RUN pnpm dlx turbo run build --filter=api...


FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

# Don't run production as root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 expressjs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 expressjs
USER expressjs
COPY --from=installer /app .

WORKDIR /app/apps/api

CMD ["pnpm", "start"]
```

this is the docker compose file :

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432-5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: backend
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  redis:
    image : redis:6.2.6-alpine
    
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./apps/api/Dockerfile
      dockerfile: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      - 9229:9229 # for debugging
    volumes:
      - ./apps/api:/usr/src/app # mount the current directory to the container ( which is a working directory mentioned in the Dockerfile)
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - /usr/src/app/.pnpm-store
    command: pnpm start:docker
    depends_on:
      - postgres # before starting the backend, start the postgres service
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: ***
      PORT: 5000
      REDIS_HOST: ****
```

I was triying to run the dockerfile with pnpm rather than running it with yarn